# Group_by in iris using mean calculation

Tags: python-iris

Is there a similar function at [iris](https://github.com/SciTools/iris) to [cf_xarray resample](https://cf-xarray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/introduction.html?highlight=resample#resample-groupby) using `mean`?

```py
dataset.cf.resample(T="Y").mean()
```

Answer (score 0):

Although not very elegant, I found a way to make it possible for `year`:

```py
import iris
import iris.coord_categorisation

def year_mean(dataset):
    # 1st step: Create an auxialiary coordinate
    iris.coord_categorisation.add_year(dataset, "time", name="year")
    # 2nd step: Mean over the auxiliary coordinate  
    result = dataset.aggregated_by(["year"], iris.analysis.MEAN)
    # 3rd step: Fix cell_methods   
    method = iris.coords.CellMethod('mean', coords=['time'], intervals='1 year')
    result.cell_methods = result.cell_methods[:-1]
    result.add_cell_method(method)
    # 4rd step: Remove the auxiliary coordinate
    result.remove_coord("year")
    return result
```

I think this produces the most [CF standard](https://cfconventions.org/) output.